# NLog: replace \r\n with actual line break in file

Tags: c#, newline, nlog

How to make NLog insert actual line breaks to the target file instead of `\r\n` in `${message}`?

I am using a config file to configure NLog as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <variable name="logDirectory" value="Logs" />
  
    <targets>
        <target name="txtFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/${shortdate}.txt" />
      
      <target name="jsonFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/${shortdate}.json" >
        <layout type="JsonLayout" IndentJson="true">
          <attribute name="time" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss}" />                          
          <attribute name="message" layout="${message:raw=true}" />
          <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception}" />
        </layout>
      </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="jsonFile"  />        
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

and I am using NLog in a C# application. The logged messages contain `Environment.NewLine` characters which are currently replaced by `\r\n` in the log file.

```
public class SomeClass
{
   static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
   
   public void DoStuff()
   {
        try
        {
         // ... some code
        }
        catch(Exception n)
        {
          string msg = "Failed to do stuff" + Environment.NewLine + 
          "Try again later";
          logger.Error(n, msg);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `${message:raw=true}` in log layout?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work. 
<target type="File" ... ><layout type="JsonLayout"><attribute name="message" layout=${message:raw=true}  /></layout></target>

Comment: Did you try to append `\r\n` to your log messages instead of `NewLine`? This should translate into the actual line break correctly

Comment: I'm guessing that you have some JSON-encoding going on, that translates the line-break into `\r\n`-chars. Think you need to update your question with the actual logging-operation (with input-parameters) and also show the NLog Target Layout configuration.

Comment: NLog JsonLayout will by default output in json-format where newline-chars are normally not permitted. Any reason for using NLog JsonLayout ? I'm guess everything is looking as expected in the `.txt` file?

Comment: @RolfKristensen: Actually I have chosen the Json format just for the sake of its resulting layout. If giving up Json would solve the issue, then why not.

Comment: @RolfKristensen: I used the text layout and it worked. if you wish, post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the NLog [JsonLayout](https://github-wiki-see.page/m/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout), then it will encode newlines as the chars `\r\n`, as required by the JSON-format.

If correct JSON output is not relevant, then you can use the option `encode="false"`:

```xml
<layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" IndentJson="true">
   <attribute name="message" layout="${message:raw=true}" encode="false" />
</layout>
```

Alternative stop using JsonLayout.